# adding pivot calculated field to report using vba

Tags: excel, pivot-table, calculated-field, vba

I have pivot table.
I manually added 3 calculated fields **f1,f2,f3**.
I want to be able to build pivot report using vba, based on the user selection.

For example:
1. First the user select a "regular" field to be added (same as dragging the field from the pivot table field list to the values area)

```
'Add a pivot Filed to graph as Y axis
Sub AddPivotFieldToColValues(fName As String)
    Dim objField As PivotField

    'Get pivot field
    Set objField = GetPivotFieldByName(fName)

    'Add to col list
    objField.Orientation = xlColumnField
End Sub

Function GetPivotFieldByName(fName As String) As PivotField
    Set GetPivotFieldByName = pivotTable.PivotFields(fName)
End Function
```

This works.

2. The user selects also calculated field **f1** to be added to report values

   ```
   Sub AddCaclulatedFieldToColValues(fName As String)
           Dim objField As PivotField

           Set objField = GetCalculatedFiledByName(fName)

           objField.Orientation = xlColumnField

   End Sub

   Function GetCalculatedFiledByName(name As String) As PivotField

       'Loop over all calculated fields
       For Each f In pivotTable.CalculatedFields

               'Test name
               If (f.name = name) Then
                       'Return field
                        Set GetCalculatedFiledByName = f

                        'Field found - exit loop
                        Exit For
               End If
      Next
   ```

   End Function

This fails when setting field Orientation.

> Run-Time Error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error

I thought it might be something with the name, as when manually adding calculated field to values, Excel the name is changing. and when trying to rename it back(via Value Field Setting -> Custom Name), the message is:

> PivotTable Field Already exist

Please advice.

Comment: You cannot add a calculated field as a row or column field, only as a value field (in main body of the table). Try doing it manually and see how Excel reacts.

Comment: @dmm Of course. xlDataField not xlColumnField. tx.